# Stripe webhook and CLI aren't accepting my signature

Tags: reactjs, next.js, request, stripe-payments, vercel

### **SOLVED: The issue was that I had my webhook key commented next to my CLI key in the .env file, thus leading to the error related. After removing it, everything runs fine with the 200 code.**

So, I've been trying to use Stripe in a simple project, but my signature isn't accepted. I keep getting a 500 even by triggering an event.

Here's my route.ts code.

```
import { prismaClient } from "@/lib/prisma";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Stripe from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: "2023-10-16",
});

export const POST = async (request: Request) => {
  // for security reasons
  const signature = request.headers.get("stripe-signature");

  if (!signature) {
    return NextResponse.error();
  }

  const text = await request.text();

  const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
    text,
    signature,
    process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET_KEY,
  );

  if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
    const session = event.data.object as any;

    const sessionWithLineItems = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(
      event.data.object.id,
      {
        expand: ["line_items"],
      },
    );

    // const lineItems = sessionWithLineItems.line_items

    // Update Order Status
    await prismaClient.order.update({
      where: {
        id: session.metadata.orderId,
      },
      data: {
        status: "PAYMENT_CONFIRMED",
      },
    });
  }

  // return to Stripe that order was created
  return NextResponse.json({ received: true });
};
```

And here's the error I receive after running a trigger or even trying to do it using my app.

```
⨯ StripeSignatureVerificationError: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?

Learn more about webhook signing and explore webhook integration examples for various frameworks at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing


Note: The provided signing secret contains whitespace. This often indicates an extra newline or space is in the value
    at validateComputedSignature (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/stripe/esm/Webhooks.js:129:19)
    at Object.verifyHeader (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/stripe/esm/Webhooks.js:65:13)
    at Object.constructEvent (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/stripe/esm/Webhooks.js:16:32)
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/order/payment-success/route.ts:18:29)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\Me\Documents\eCommerce\store\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62499 {
  type: 'StripeSignatureVerificationError',
  raw: {
    message: 'No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? \n' +
      '\n' +
      'Learn more about webhook signing and explore webhook integration examples for various frameworks at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing\n' +
      '\n' +
      '\n' +
      'Note: The provided signing secret contains whitespace. This often indicates an extra newline or space is in the value'
  },
  rawType: undefined,
  code: undefined,
  doc_url: undefined,
  param: undefined,
  detail: undefined,
  headers: undefined,
  requestId: undefined,
  statusCode: undefined,
  charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  payment_method_type: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined,
  header: 't=1698790341,v1=6a2b7ea54c701da2832706e9f2d70c4d46e25cac3c7aa7359790ae073389af1e,v0=619bbfb51355c1e0d0e85cf6c12e66f9e60fede61ac1b284f72c4b019085fc18',
  payload: '{\n' +
    '  "id": "evt_3O7QAaKblwZEYNxi1L6n6aiP",\n' +
    '  "object": "event",\n' +
    '  "api_version": "2023-10-16",\n' +
    '  "created": 1698790341,\n' +
    '  "data": {\n' +
    '    "object": {\n' +
    '      "id": "ch_3O7QAaKblwZEYNxi1mWQSXlO",\n' +
    '      "object": "charge",\n' +
    '      "amount": 2000,\n' +
    '      "amount_captured": 2000,\n' +
    '      "amount_refunded": 0,\n' +
    '      "application": null,\n' +
    '      "application_fee": null,\n' +
    '      "application_fee_amount": null,\n' +
    '      "balance_transaction": "txn_3O7QAaKblwZEYNxi13GFfwDS",\n' +
    '      "billing_details": {\n' +
    '        "address": {\n' +
    '          "city": null,\n' +
    '          "country": null,\n' +
    '          "line1": null,\n' +
    '          "line2": null,\n' +
    '          "postal_code": null,\n' +
    '          "state": null\n' +
    '        },\n' +
    '        "email": null,\n' +
    '        "name": null,\n' +
    '        "phone": null\n' +
    '      },\n' +
    '      "calculated_statement_descriptor": "Stripe",\n' +
    '      "captured": true,\n' +
    '      "created": 1698790340,\n' +
    '      "currency": "usd",\n' +
    '      "customer": null,\n' +
    '      "description": "(created by Stripe CLI)",\n' +
    '      "destination": null,\n' +
    '      "dispute": null,\n' +
    '      "disputed": false,\n' +
    '      "failure_balance_transaction": null,\n' +
    '      "failure_code": null,\n' +
    '      "failure_message": null,\n' +
    '      "fraud_details": {\n' +
    '      },\n' +
    '      "invoice": null,\n' +
    '      "livemode": false,\n' +
    '      "metadata": {\n' +
    '      },\n' +
    '      "on_behalf_of": null,\n' +
    '      "order": null,\n' +
    '      "outcome": {\n' +
    '        "network_status": "approved_by_network",\n' +
    '        "reason": null,\n' +
    '        "risk_level": "normal",\n' +
    '        "risk_score": 34,\n' +
    '        "seller_message": "Payment complete.",\n' +
    '        "type": "authorized"\n' +
    '      },\n' +
    '      "paid": true,\n' +
    '      "payment_intent": "pi_3O7QAaKblwZEYNxi1nfN8Zac",\n' +
    '      "payment_method": "pm_1O7QAaKblwZEYNxiQcXclN08",\n' +
    '      "payment_method_details": {\n' +
    '        "card": {\n' +
    '          "amount_authorized": 2000,\n' +
    '          "brand": "visa",\n' +
    '          "checks": {\n' +
    '            "address_line1_check": null,\n' +
    '            "address_postal_code_check": null,\n' +
    '            "cvc_check": "pass"\n' +
    '          },\n' +
    '          "country": "US",\n' +
    '          "exp_month": 10,\n' +
    '          "exp_year": 2024,\n' +
    '          "extended_authorization": {\n' +
    '            "status": "disabled"\n' +
    '          },\n' +
    '          "fingerprint": "UXCDlnxMq7Vt8nxA",\n' +
    '          "funding": "credit",\n' +
    '          "incremental_authorization": {\n' +
    '            "status": "unavailable"\n' +
    '          },\n' +
    '          "installments": null,\n' +
    '          "last4": "4242",\n' +
    '          "mandate": null,\n' +
    '          "multicapture": {\n' +
    '            "status": "unavailable"\n' +
    '          },\n' +
    '          "network": "visa",\n' +
    '          "network_token": {\n' +
    '            "used": false\n' +
    '          },\n' +
    '          "overcapture": {\n' +
    '            "maximum_amount_capturable": 2000,\n' +
    '            "status": "unavailable"\n' +
    '          },\n' +
    '          "three_d_secure": null,\n' +
    '          "wallet": null\n' +
    '        },\n' +
    '        "type": "card"\n' +
    '      },\n' +
    '      "receipt_email": null,\n' +
    '      "receipt_number": null,\n' +
    '      "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/payment/CAcaFwoVYWNjdF8xTzVidk9LYmx3WkVZTnhpKMX3haoGMgYjHoPmDJE6LBa0KbOzCefBJbOcbTEd1vxy1Nqjlg8TEq_o0b770SWZWo1iY9PSJTCdIoXy",\n' +      
    '      "refunded": false,\n' +
    '      "review": null,\n' +
    '      "shipping": {\n' +
    '        "address": {\n' +
    '          "city": "San Francisco",\n' +
    '          "country": "US",\n' +
    '          "line1": "510 Townsend St",\n' +
    '          "line2": null,\n' +
    '          "postal_code": "94103",\n' +
    '          "state": "CA"\n' +
    '        },\n' +
    '        "carrier": null,\n' +
    '        "name": "Jenny Rosen",\n' +
    '        "phone": null,\n' +
    '        "tracking_number": null\n' +
    '      },\n' +
    '      "source": null,\n' +
    '      "source_transfer": null,\n' +
    '      "statement_descriptor": null,\n' +
    '      "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,\n' +
    '      "status": "succeeded",\n' +
    '      "transfer_data": null,\n' +
    '      "transfer_group": null\n' +
    '    }\n' +
    '  },\n' +
    '  "livemode": false,\n' +
    '  "pending_webhooks": 2,\n' +
    '  "request": {\n' +
    '    "id": "req_UaVNa9xsciNCyv",\n' +
    '    "idempotency_key": "edf2322d-4736-4c84-890b-2aa725060724"\n' +
    '  },\n' +
    '  "type": "charge.succeeded"\n' +
    '}'
}
```

I've tried different things like using buffer and even reinstalled Stripe CLI using Scoop, but this same error keeps appearing.
Because of that, my webhook isn't working either, like the local tests.

Comment: When you construct the event to perform signature verification, Stripe requires that you use the raw body of the Event you received. Any changes/modification to this body will result in a failed match.

Based on the above, it looks like you need to replace `request.text()` with `request.body()` so your code uses the raw body of the event, not a text representation of it.

If that doesn't help, you may want to look at this issue in case other solutions are a better fit for your existing environment: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/341